# Value of a vector

Tags: matrices, vectors

I’ve got a question that asks me for a value of a vector at a particular time. It is just basic addition but I’m not sure about the form of the answer. Should I leave it as w=(x, y, z) or calculate the absolute value of the vector?

Edit: 
z=[0, 0, sin(c)] 
d=[c, cos(c),0] 
f=z+d 
It’s simple vector addition. 
I’m supposed to find the value of f at c=0. 
Should I leave it as [0, 1, 0] or calculate the absolute value which is 1?

Comment: This is not at all clear. You say you've "got a question" but don't tell us what the question actually is. Please [edit] your post to provide that information. (Do it by editing, not in comments.) Then perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $f$ is different from the norm of $f$.

Just leave it as $[0,0, \sin(0)] + [0,\cos(0), 0]= [0,1,0]$ as you computed.